# Different output in C and C++ with sizeof operator

Tags: c++, c

Why does this code produces different o/p in C and C++?

```
int i = sizeof('a');
```

Comment: Is treated as a constant of int in C, but it is treated as a char in C ++.

Answer (score 3):

In C, the type of a character constant like `'a'` is actually an `int`, with size of 4 (or some other implementation-dependent value). In C++, the type is `char`, with size of 1. This is one of many small differences between the two languages.

Answer (score 2):

Character literals in C are `int`s, whereas in C++ they are `char`s. In any case `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition.

Answer (score 1):

This is because C and C++ define character literals differently. In C, character literals are treated as `int` while in C++ they are treated as `char`.